# What is best method to format DateTime to allow DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) in a WHERE clause to filter results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

REPHRASED QUESTION:

I am attempting to extract results from only the previous Working Day (target working days being Monday - Friday). I have worked the below code backwards to locate the part that seems to cause the problem as follows:

```
SELECT Jobid, Type
FROM [MYTABLE]
WHERE [MYDATECOLUMN]>= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND [MYDATECOLUMN]< dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

This produces correct results and lists the JobId and Type of job from the previous day.

As MYDATE column is a DateTime, I am trying to CAST, CONVERT or FORMAT this in order to work in conjunction with my CASE statement as below which has GETDATE()), the with aim to change results from reflecting those that occurred "yesterday" to reflecting "previous working day".

When trying to use CAST, FORMAT, CONVERT alongside CASE there are 0 results. From the very helpful previous comments, I believe this may be due to the DateTime and GETDATE()) dealing with separate specificity scales!

Thanks in advance! "problem" Snippet below -I have commented out the 3 options I have tried to get the DATE from DATETIME - but may be the GETDATE()) in my CASE statement causing the conflict?

I have attempted each option individually to no end yet.

```
SELECT  [JobId], 
        [Type], 
/*Option 1*/--CAST(MYDATECOLUMN AS DATE) 
/*Option 2*/--CONVERT(varchar(10), RealStart, 111)
/*Option 3*/--FORMAT(MYDATECOLUMN, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
FROM [MYTABLE]
WHERE [MYDATECOLUMN] = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                    ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))
```

I hope the first and second code snippets provide some insight and my troubleshooting thus far - although I will indeed take the tour as recommended yesterday!

Thanks again!

Comment: Does `MYDATECOLUMN` contain non-zero time for some rows?

Comment: As an aside, handling anything to do with working days is almost always best handled with a [calendar table](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+calendar+table) with an `IsWorkingDay` flag, or potentially an ancillary holiday table (if your work place covers multiple regions with different public holidays). You then have a fairly simply query to get the previous working day, not just the previous weekday: `(SELECT TOP 1 c.Date FROM dbo.Calendar AS c WHERE c.Date < GETDATE() ORDER BY c.Date DESC)`

Comment: You've changed the logic in the where clause from your first query to your second. Your first query has `WHERE Date > PreviousDay AND date <= CurrentDay`, your second is simply `WHERE Date = PreviousWorkingDay`. I think your 2nd query would work if you implemented the same logic as the first but changed `previousday` to `previousworkingday`

Comment: Hello! The MYDATE column is down to 100ths of a second - reflecting the exact time someone recognised they are beginning a task on a management system.

Comment: Thank you for the calendar advice! I will look into implementing this for simplicity!

Comment: Thank you GarethD, I will give this a whorl as well as the answer from Salaman A! Much Appreciated!

Comment: As a further aside, I'd be inclined to avoid `DATENAME()` as it will be language specific. It may be unlikely to ever be an issue, but why take the chance. You can make this independent of region using `@@DATEFIRST()`, e.g. `DATEADD(DAY, CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7  WHEN 1 THEN -2 WHEN 2 THEN -3 ELSE -1 END, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE));`.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to use `datetimecolumn >= ... AND datetimecolumn < ...` to check if a date+time column is between two ***dates***. So you must repeat the `SELECT DATEADD()` logic twice (one to the the previous day and other to calculate previous day + 1 day). I however prefer to use `CROSS APPLY` to minimize repeated code:

```sql
FROM [MYTABLE]
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS thisday
) AS ca1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, thisday)
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2
        WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3
        ELSE -1 END, thisday) AS prevday
) AS ca2
WHERE MYDATECOLUMN >= prevday AND MYDATECOLUMN < DATEADD(DAY, 1, prevday)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will take this and have a play! Much appreciated :)

Comment: Be advised I fixed two typos in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This version of your code *should* be working:

```
WHERE CAST(MYDATECOLUMN as DATE) = DATEADD(DAY,
                                           CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                                               WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                                               WHEN 'Monday' THEN -3 
                                               ELSE -1
                                           END, 
                                           CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                                          )
```

You specify this as an option in your comments.  If this is not working, please explain what the specific issue is -- an error, it doesn't work one certain days.  There are various possibilities, such as a time zone issue or your system settings set to a language other than English.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff! Thanks for taking the time! I have popped that in to SQL and it does indeed come up with yesterday (which happens to be previous working day! but can test on Monday to see if Friday pops up in the results! - Thanks again!

Comment: @CameronA . . . You can test the code for any date by replacing `getdate()` with a constant.  Or sometimes I just use `getdate() + 3` or something like that.